# Finding lines of symmetry algebraically

Tags: calculus

How would you determine the lines of symmetry of the curve $y=f(x)$ without sketching the curve itself?

I was working on the problem of finding the lines of symmetry of the curve given by:

$ x^{4}$+$ y^{4}$ = $u$ where u is a positive real number.

but I had to resort to doing a quick sketch.

Is there an explicit condition for a line to be considered a line of symmetry of a curve?

Thanks.

Comment: For curves that have simple analytical expression it's quite easy to see which transformations of variables leave curve unchanged. For example, you can see that for any point $(x_0, y_0)$ which belongs to curve $x^4 + y^4 = u$ it's true that points $(-x_0, y_0)$, $(x_0, -y_0)$ and $(-x_0, -y_0)$ also belong to it. From each of these observations follows that curve has $Oy$ and $Ox$ as lines of symmetry and it's center symmetric.

Comment: What would happen with more complicated curves? How would you determine if a curve has a line of a symmetry in the first place? I am familiar with odd and even functions but these only concern curves whose line of symmetry is the y axis, do they not?

Comment: Well, even function (to be correct, it's graph on $Oxy$ plane) has $Oy$ as line of symmetry, but odd function is center symmetric: you need to switch both $x$ and $y$ to $-x$ and $-y$ to obtain the same curve (check it, it's easy). Frankly speaking in most cases there's no other way to know whether set has some symmetry or not except direct check. IMHO, all other cases are just a sublime of your experience in thoroughly solved similar problems or ability to quickly check some very simple substitutions in equations :)

Comment: So in most cases it is sufficient to simply test a few cases?  I was just concerned with dealing with complicated functions that aren't clearly symmetrical. Thanks.

Comment: Yep. And if you are interested only in curves $y = f(x)$, then you have to check just two possible symmetries.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are able to determine the *center of gravity* of the region enclosed by the curve, any *line of symmetry* has to go through that. If that center is $(s,t)$, then you should only consider lines of the form
$$
a(x-s)+b(y-t)=0
$$

---

For your example, clearly $x^4+y^4=u$ for constant $u$ has center of mass $(0,0)$, so you should only consider lines of the form
$$
ax+by=0
$$

Answer (score 1):

The line $x=0$ is a symmetry line, because if a point $P=(x_1,y_1)$ fulfills the equation, then $(-x_1,y_1)$ ($P$ reflected about the $y$-axis) does too.

Similarly, if $Q=(x_2,y_2)$ fulfills the equation, then so does $(y_2,x_2)$, which is $Q$ reflected about the line $x=y$. Therefore that line is also a symmetry line for the curve.

There are more symmetry lines, but this is how you look for them. I think you should be able to find the other two on your own.

Comment: I was wondering whether there was a general approach or condition for a line to be considered a line of symmetry. Something like, "the line l is a line of symmetry of the curve $f(x)$ if and only if l satisfies...."

Comment: Well, Taylor series give you such condition for curves $y = f(x)$ (to some extent). If Taylor series of function $f(x)$ only contains terms with even powers, then $f(x)$ is even, curve is $Oy$-symmetric. If it has only terms with odd powers, $f(x)$ is odd and center-symmetric. Of course, all these results are true in domains where this series converges. For graphs (i.e., curves $(x, f(x))$) these are only two possible symmetries.

Answer (score 0):

A line L given by $ax+by+c=0$ is a line of symmetry for your curve, if and only if for any point $P_1(x_1,y_1)$ from the curve, its symmetrical point $P_2(x_2,y_2)$ (with respect to the line L) is also on the curve.

Now:
(1) express $x_2$ and $y_2$ as functions of $x_1, y_1$ (this can be done from the equation of L);
(2) substitute the $x_2$ and $y_2$ expressions in the curve equation (because they should satisfy it too); thus you'll get the "iff condition" which you're looking for.

In the general case i.e. for any arbitrary curve, it won't be a nice equation, I believe.

Comment: Would you mind demonstrating how to do this with the example given as I'm not completely following?

Answer (score 0):

By definition, G
  has line of symmetry $y=px+q$
  if for every point $(\alpha,\beta)\in G$
 , its reflection point is also in $G$
 .

By the Lemma below, its reflection point is $\left(\frac{2p(\beta-q)+(1-p^{2})\alpha}{p^{2}+1},\frac{(p^{2}-1)\beta+2p\alpha+2q}{p^{2}+1}\right)$
 .

Hence, a graph $G$
  has line of symmetry $y=px+q$
  if and only if:

$$(\alpha,\beta)\in G\implies \left(\frac{2p(\beta-q)+(1-p^{2})\alpha}{p^{2}+1},\frac{(p^{2}-1)\beta+2p\alpha+2q}{p^{2}+1}\right)$$

$\\$

$\\$

**Lemma.** The reflection point of $(\alpha,\beta)$
  on the line $y=px+q$
  is $$\left(\frac{2p(\beta-q)+(1-p^{2})\alpha}{p^{2}+1},\frac{(p^{2}-1)\beta+2p\alpha+2q}{p^{2}+1}\right)$$

*Proof.* Let $y=-(1/p)x+r$
  be the line that is perpendicular to the line of symmetry and which runs through $(\alpha,\beta)$
 . Then $\beta=-(1/p)\alpha+r
  \implies
 r=\beta+\alpha/p$.

So the equation of that perpendicular line is $y=-(1/p)x+\beta+\alpha/p$
 .

The intersection point of this perpendicular line with the original line of symmetry is given by:

$$px+q= -(1/p)x+\beta+\alpha/p \\
(p+1/p)x= \beta+\alpha/p-q \\
x= \frac{p\beta+\alpha-pq}{p^{2}+1}=\frac{p(\beta-q)+\alpha}{p^{2}+1} \\
y= px+q \\
y= p\frac{p(\beta-q)+\alpha}{p^{2}+1}+q \\
y= \frac{p^{2}(\beta-q)+p\alpha+(p^{2}+1)q}{p^{2}+1} \\
y= \frac{p^{2}\beta+p\alpha+q}{p^{2}+1} $$

The reflection point is twice as far away from $(\alpha,\beta)$
  as is the above intersection point. So the reflection point is:

$$\left(2\frac{p(\beta-q)+\alpha}{p^{2}+1}-\alpha,2\frac{p^{2}\beta+p\alpha+q}{p^{2}+1}-\beta\right) \\
= \left(\frac{2p(\beta-q)+2\alpha-(p^{2}+1)\alpha}{p^{2}+1},\frac{2p^{2}\beta+2p\alpha+2q-(p^{2}+1)\beta}{p^{2}+1}\right) \\
= \left(\frac{2p(\beta-q)+(1-p^{2})\alpha}{p^{2}+1},\frac{(p^{2}-1)\beta+2p\alpha+2q}{p^{2}+1}\right) \blacksquare $$